# getting an error 'AttributeError:' in Python

Tags: python

I have written the below script using python:

```
class Fruit:

  def __init__(self,name):
      self.name = name
      print "Initialized Fruit Name: %s" % self.name

  def tell(self):
      print "U have entered the fruit as %s" % self.name

class Sweet(Fruit):

  def __init__(self,name,taste,price):
      Fruit.__init__(self,name)
      self.taste = taste
      print "Initialized the name of the fruit as %s" % self.name

  def tell(self):
      Fruit.tell(self)
      print "Taste of the fruit is %s" % self.taste

  def sayPrice(self):
      Fruit.tell(self)                 
      print "The price of the fruit Mango is %d" % self.price

class Salt(Fruit):

  def __init__(self,name,taste,price):
      Fruit.__init__(self,name)
      self.taste = taste
      print "Initialized the name of the fruit as %s" % self.name

  def tell(self):
      Fruit.tell(self)
      print "Taste of the fruit is %s" % self.taste

  def sayPrice(self):
      Fruit.tell(self)
      print "The price of the fruit Strawberry is %d" % self.price

m = Sweet('Mango','sweet',100)

s = Salt('Strawberry','salty',50)

choice = raw_input("enter ur choice:(Mango/Strawberry):")

if choice == 'Mango':
    m.tell()
else:
    s.tell()

decision = raw_input("Do U want to know the price?(Y/N)")

if decision == 'Y' and choice == 'Mango':

    m.sayPrice()
elif decision == 'Y' and choice == 'Strawberry':

    s.sayPrice() 
else:
    print "Sad to see U go :(, please do visit next time again"
```

And below is the error I am getting:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Python26/Inheritance_practice2.py", line 47, in
>
> ```
> m.sayPrice()
> ```
>
> File "C:/Python26/Inheritance_practice2.py", line 21, in sayPrice
>
> ```
> print "The price of the fruit Mango is %d" % self.price
> ```
>
> AttributeError: Sweet instance has no attribute 'price'
>
> NOTE: The error is thrown when the user wants to know the price of the
>   chosen fruit.

Comment: Please cut this down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); we don't need to see everything. But you never assign `self.price`, so this shouldn't have been surprising.

Comment: And where do you think you are setting the price? Point to the code that does it.

Comment: For the love of all that is pythonic, please wrap up your script code with a `if __name__ == "__main__":`.

Comment: Also, why bother always passing `'salty'` to `Salt`? Surely `taste` should be a `Fruit` attribute, then e.g. `Salt` *doesn't* take that argument and always passes `'salty'` to `super(Salt, self).__init__(...)`? That way all `Fruit` has a `taste`, and all `Salt` has `taste == 'salty'`.

Comment: How can I do the wrapping of this code using if ______name______ = "______main______" could you please paste the code here.Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need `self.price=price` in the `__init__` methods - currently you are just throwing that parameter away.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `self.price`, preferably to `Fruit`:

```
class Fruit:
    def __init__(self,name,price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price #set price when initiated.
        (...)

class Sweet(Fruit):
    def __init__(self,name,taste,price):
        Fruit.__init__(self,name,price) #send price as init parameter
        self.taste = taste
        print "Initialized the name of the fruit as %s" % self.name
    (..)
```

Comment: Strictly not to the classes, but to the instances.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is a better option add that attribute to you parent class fruit

```
class Fruit:

  def __init__(self,name, price):
      self.name = name
      self.price = price
      print "Initialized Fruit Name: %s" % self.name

  def tell(self):
      print "U have entered the fruit as %s" % self.name

class Sweet(Fruit):

  def __init__(self,name,taste,price):
      Fruit.__init__(self,name, price)
      self.taste = taste
     print "Initialized the name of the fruit as %s" % self.name

  def tell(self):
      Fruit.tell(self)
      print "Taste of the fruit is %s" % self.taste

  def sayPrice(self):
      Fruit.tell(self)                 
      print "The price of the fruit Mango is %d" % self.price

class Salt(Fruit):

  def __init__(self,name,taste,price):
      Fruit.__init__(self,name, price)
      self.taste = taste
      print "Initialized the name of the fruit as %s" % self.name

  def tell(self):
      Fruit.tell(self)
      print "Taste of the fruit is %s" % self.taste

  def sayPrice(self):
      Fruit.tell(self)
      print "The price of the fruit Strawberry is %d" % self.price
```

Works fine as well. Also you can add a getter in your Fruit class to obtain the price, saving lines of code  and using the advantage given by the OOP because your children classes are inheriting the method